# Unable to retrieve prices and legal terms when creating Azure OpenAI service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azureportal, azure-openai

I am trying to create an Azure OpenAI service, but in the final 4th step (Review + submit) I repeatedly encountered an error:

> Unable to retrieve prices and legal terms

I cannot create the resource, the **Create** button is disabled.

Our application for the Azure OpenAI Service was accepted for this subscription.

I aim to create the service in the West Europe region with Standard S0 pricing and allowing all networks to access it. However, I tried all available regions and network settings (the pricing didn't have other options), but I ran into the same issue.

I asked the subscription owners to create the service, but they got the same error, so it's not a privilege issue.

Also tried in incognito mode and various browsers (Edge, Chrome, Brave and Safari).

The Service Health Dashboard shows there are no issues in any location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to create the resource via azure-cli instead of the portal. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/create-resource?pivots=cli). Much gratitude for AshokPeddakotla-MSFT for [their recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1332936/unable-to-retrieve-prices-and-legal-terms-when-cre).

Answer (score -2):

To troubleshoot and resolve this issue, I recommend the following steps:

Wait and Retry: Sometimes, the issue can be temporary. Wait for a while (several hours or a day) and try creating the Azure OpenAI service again. Azure service interruptions are often resolved automatically, and the process may work later.

Contact Azure Support: If the problem persists, reach out to Azure Support for assistance. You can do this through the Azure portal by clicking on "Help + support" and then "New support request." Provide detailed information about the error you encountered, the steps you've taken, and the regions/network settings you tried. Azure Support can investigate the issue and provide a more specific resolution.

Check Azure Status: Even if the Service Health Dashboard shows no issues, check the Azure status page (https://status.azure.com/) to see if there are any ongoing incidents or known problems related to the Azure OpenAI service.

Consider Different Pricing Tiers: If you are set on using the West Europe region and are unable to create the service with the Standard S0 pricing, you can try creating it with a different pricing tier (e.g., S1) or in a different region (e.g., East US, West US, etc.). It's possible that there might be a temporary issue with the specific pricing tier in the West Europe region.

If none of the above steps resolve the issue, Azure Support is your best resource to get to the root cause of the problem and help you create the Azure OpenAI service successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. 

I tried contacting Azure Support, but they only provide paid support and signing up for a Developer support plan takes days as well. However, I managed to contact them on their Twitter page: https://twitter.com/AzureSupport and they granted me a free support request.

Their status page doesn't show any disruption either.

No other pricing tiers are available for us.

Comment: thats great, thanks for letting knoow

Comment: can u try their support over twitter

Comment: I did - as I already said in my previous comment.

Comment: But everything is solved, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76736730/2380553

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).